# 200 millions items at Vector

Tags: c++, list, vector

Here is my structure

```
struct Node
{
 int chrN;
 long int pos;
 int nbp;
 string Ref;
 string Alt;
};
```

to fill the structure I read though a file and pars my interest variable to the structure and then push it back to a vectore. The problem is, there are around 200 millions items and I should keep all of them at memory (for the further steps)! But the program terminated after pushing back 50 millions of nodes with bad_allocation error.

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
what():  std::bad_alloc
```

searching around give me the idea I'm out of memory! but the output of top shows %48 (when the termination happened)

Additional information which may be useful:
I set the stack limitation unlimit and 
I'm using Ubuntu x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux with 4Gb RAM.

Any help whuold be most welcome.

**Update:**

1st switch from vector to list, then store each ~500Mb at file and index them for further analyses.

Comment: You are probably out of memory, a hole big enough to fit the vector.  You got the right flavor of Linux to build your program as a 64-bit executable and get gobs of virtual memory.

Comment: Think about what you're going to do with the data and design your solution around that, you may not need all the data all the time. You might even find that stuffing the data into a database will do the job good enough for your needs.

Comment: @HansPassant: +1 In 32bits chances are that there is no virtual memory space for all those `Node` objects, even if there was absolutely nothing else in memory. If that many objects need to be in memory he **needs** 64bits

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vector storage is contiguous, in this case, 200 mio * the sizeof the struct bytes are required. For each of the strings in the struct, another mini allocation *may* be needed to hold the string. All together, this is not going to fit your available address space, and no (non-compressing) data structure is going to solve this.

Vectors usually grow their backing capacity exponentially (which amortizes the cost for `push_back`). So when your program was already using about half the available address space, the vector probably attempted to double its size (or add 50%), which then caused the `bad_alloc` and it did not free the previous buffer, so the final memory appears to be only 48%.

Comment: it is contiguous in virtual memory, not physical memory. So it doesn't really matter that it is contiguous in virtual memory

Comment: Edited for address space.

Comment: He's got a 64-bit address space. There should be plenty of contiguous room for his vector, even while resizing.

Comment: In addition, the allocations done by `vector` (allocate larger block, copy, free smaller block) are the worst possible case for an allocator. Every freed block is guaranteed not to be reusable by future allocations. It will have used up all available address space a lot earlier than when trying to double a half-address-space-sized allocation.

Answer (score 2):

That node structure consumes up to 44 bytes, plus the actual string buffers. There's no way 200 million of them will fit in 4 GB.

You need to not hold your entire dataset in memory at once.

Comment: Good point.  I forget about std::strings often carrying a small block for small-string-optimization.

Comment: @LatencyMachine: Even if there were no strings, 32bits of address space are not sufficient to address just the `Node` objects1

Answer (score 0):

Since vectors must store all elements in *contiguous* memory, you are much more likely to run out of memory before you consume your full available RAM.

Try using a std::list and see if that can retain all of your items.  You won't be able to randomly access the elements, but that is a tradeoff you are most likely going to have to deal with.

The std::list can better utilize free fragments of RAM, since unlike the vector, it doesn't try to store the elements adjacent to one another.

Comment: Or a [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) if array-like indexing is wanted.

Comment: imagine 200 billions allocation for std::list. bad-bad-bad. as the result the memory will be defragmented, performance will get down

Comment: also std::list consumes extra info for each item, so std::list in this case is not suitable

Comment: std::list is not going to fix this case. It would not even fit in contiguous storage, with the overhead for all the mini heap allocations needed for list noded it would be even worse (even though the perceived RAM use / point of failure) may occur later.

Comment: contiguous virtual memory does not imply contiguous physical memory, so I don't see how much more likely you run out of memory beforehand

Comment: I agree with others that the memory consumed by his records alone are too much, regardless of the data structure.

Comment: He's got a 64 bit virtual memory space... the issue here is NOT contiguous memory, but memory period.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the size of the data types, I'd guess, the structure you are using is at least 4+8+4+2+2=20 Bytes long. If you have 200 000 000 of data fields, this will be around 3,8 gb of data. Not sure what you read from top, but this is close to your memory limit.

As LatencyMachine noted, the items have to be in a contiguous memory block, which will be difficult (the string memory can be somewhere else, but the two bytes I summed up will have to be in the vector).

It might help to initialize the vector with the correct size to avoid reallocation.

Comment: The `+2+2` does not seem right. `long int` might be 4 or 8, but `std::string` will not be 2 bytes in *any* platform! With real sizes, it is not close, but well beyond the size of the address space

Comment: Well, I said *at least*. It is possible to store the reference to a empty string in 2 bytes, this depends on the actual implementation. This will not be beyond the size of the address space which is 2^64 Bytes on a 64 bit platform. It might be beyond the size of the actual memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a look at this code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
struct Node
{
 int chrN;
 long int pos;
 int nbp;
 string Ref;
 string Alt;
};
int main() {
    // your code goes here
    cout << sizeof(Node) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

And the result it produces on [ideone](http://ideone.com/PFhpbT) you will find out that the size of your structure even if the strings are empty and on 32 bit computer is 20. Thus `200 * 10^6` times this size makes exactly 4GB. You can't hope to have the whole memory just for you. So your program will use virtual memory like crazy. You **have** to think of a way to store the elements only partially or your program will be in huge trouble.